# Rails controller respond_with json from two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I want to `respond_to :json` in my locations_controller from both my location and beer models.

My locations controller looks like this

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
respond_to :html, :json
  # GET /locations
  # GET /locations.json
  def index
    @locations = Location.all
     respond_with(@locations,:only => [:id,:lat,:long,:name,:street_address,:place,:route],:methods => [:main_url, :beer_name])
  end
```

@beer belongs_to :location and I would like :name from the beer model to be added to the above location response. This is my `beers_controller`.

```
class BeersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json
  # GET /beers
  # GET /beers.json

  def index
    @beers = Beer.where(:location_id => params[:location_id])
    respond_with(@beers,:only => [:id,:name,:description,:price,:style,:location_id, :brewery, :available],:methods => [:label_url])      
  end
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:
https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

Rabl provides a simple way for you to retrieve all relationships on objects, and you can build your json in a clean and easy way.

As your beer model belongs_to a location, you have two options:

- If location has_one beer, you can access direcly
  `location.beer.name`, this meaning, the name from the beer from this
  location.
- If you location has_many beer(s), you can make a loop to iterate on
  every beer for a location:

Code:

```
location.beers.each do |beer| 
   puts beer.name
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. Is there a way to do it without adding a gem like Rabl?

Comment: Let's say that the code you are using is ugly. Just compare it to mine. Yours is not ruby-style. You should consider the best and simpler option, that will be great for the future of your project. What you did is an ugly un-maintainable hack.

Comment: Ok, let's say it is an ugly un-maintainable hack like you said. Can you suggest an option that accomplishes my goal without using the rabl gem?

Comment: Whats the problem in using this gem exactly?

Comment: No problem with the gem, I'm simply trying to learn how rails can handle this type of functionality on it's own prior to using a gem.

Answer (score 0):

the rabl gem looks like a good way to go but I decided to add this to my location model

```
def as_json(options={})
    super(:only => [:id,:lat,:long,:name,:street_address,:place,:route], :methods => [:main_url],
          :include => {
            :beers => {:only => [:name]}
          }
    )
  end
```

This does the trick for me.

Comment: Even if it fix your problem, this is a really bad code, for the reasons I wrote above.

Comment: I want an option that doesn't involve using the rabl gem, and this is what I came up with.